# Installing Packages in react-native, throwing error of "unable to resolve depedendency"

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-install

I am attempting to install the following packages in react-native:

npx expo install @react-navigation/native@5.9.8 @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9 react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view expo-constants

It has thrown the following error log:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: nucampsite@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: react-native-safe-area-context@3.4.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm WARN   react-native-safe-area-context@"4.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (react-native-elements, @react-navigation/stack)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-native-elements
npm WARN   react-native-elements@"3.4.2" from the root project        
npm WARN deprecated @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11: Repository was moved to @react-native-masked-view/masked-view

added 25 packages, removed 1 package, changed 2 packages, and audited 1185 packages in 12s

54 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

> npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR! Found: react-native-safe-area-context@4.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@">= 0.6.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/stack@"5.14.9" from the root project   
npm ERR!   react-native-safe-area-context@"4.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-elements
npm ERR!   react-native-elements@"3.4.2" from the root project        
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-safe-area-context@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-elements
npm ERR!     react-native-elements@"3.4.2" from the root project      
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\isena\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-09T22_33_54_680Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\isena\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-09T22_33_54_680Z-debug-0.log
```

here is my **package-json:**

```
{
  "name": "nucampsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^46.0.13",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.69.6",
    "react-native-elements": "3.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have tried **updating react with npm install react@latest**

which threw me the following error log:

```
    npm install react@latest
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: nucampsite@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm WARN     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm WARN   13 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/native, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm WARN   11 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: nucampsite@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm WARN     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm WARN   13 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/native, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm WARN   11 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: nucampsite@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm WARN     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm WARN   13 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/native, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm WARN   11 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: nucampsite@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm WARN     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm WARN   13 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/native, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm WARN   11 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: nucampsite@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm WARN     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm WARN   13 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/native, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm WARN   11 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: nucampsite@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm WARN     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm WARN   13 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/native, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm WARN   11 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: nucampsite@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm WARN     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm WARN   13 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/native, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm WARN   11 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...)
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR! Found: react-native-safe-area-context@4.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@">= 0.6.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/stack@"5.14.9" from the root project
npm ERR!   react-native-safe-area-context@"4.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-elements
npm ERR!   react-native-elements@"3.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-safe-area-context@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-elements
npm ERR!     react-native-elements@"3.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

The fix I discovered was very simple: instead of forcing the installs through with --force or --legacy-peer-deps, I actually deleted the line

```
 "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1"
```

from my package.json.

I am in a coding bootcamp and that is the solution we figured out with our instructor.